# How to Get the Azure key vault certificate activation date using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate

I am looking to get the activation date of a certificate from a key vault. is there any powershell command available.

Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate I am able to get the Created date but not the activation date.

Answer (score 0):

***I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate?view=azps-8.2.0) and tried to reproduce in my environment:***

```
Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName 'rithwikkey' | Select-Object Name,Created
```

[image]

***Alternatively, you can get the activation date using portal:***

[image]

***These are the only properties coming with the command:***

```
Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName 'rithwikkey'
```

[image]

***You can check Activation Details on Clicking Certificate:***

[image]

***You can get not before and not after using this command:***
***Not before is used as activation date and***
***Not After is used as expiration date in general terms***

```
Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName 'rithwikkey' -name 'rithwik'
```

[image]